# Update User A data to User B in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing a simple social app, Where Users can register and make friends with other users. Users can share text, images, videos with other users. What i want is if userA adds any image to server from iPhone app how can userB receive automatically that image without clicking any buttons. how can server sends to userB's device without userB's interaction. should i have to check from my ios code to server to see if there is any update from userA every second  or is there any technique.

I just want guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official and recommended way to achieve this is using push notifications. Basically is user B is friend of user A, when user A uploads an image in the server "tagging" user B then your server will send a push notification to user B (supposing user B enabled push notification for that app). At this point user B will see the notification and will open the app: your app, knowing that it has been opened from that push notification, will download the image from the server. With iOS7 your push notification can also ask for immediate download of some content: this is called the "remote-notification" background mode and gives your app max 30" to download the content before the notification is presented on screen: in such case when the user opens the app from the notification alert the image has been already downloaded, improving the overall app experience.

Another possibility if your app is targeting iOS7 only is to use background fetch: in such case your app will periodically contact your server to know about new contents from friends. This approach at first sight seems to be preferable than using the push notifications one, but its major drawback is that you cannot control exactly when the fetch will happen, as it is the operating system that at end will do the real fetch, also based on the device conditions (low battery, no Wi-Fi) so the effective communication is unpredictable; besides the system can penalise your app if downloads take longer (so don't use it for videos). Push notifications instead are much more faster.

Comment: ok. Suppose if userB is running the app, during that period of time if userA adds some data or Images. how can i automatically adds to UITableView without userB clicking on refresh button or pull to refresh. is there any ways

Comment: If userB is running the app you have two choices: still respond to the push notification by triggering the image fetch and then the table view reload. Other possibility, as the app is in the foreground, you can periodically test for new updates from friends; however this last solution is inefficient and could easily drain battery if in 3G, so you should trim it carefully.

Comment: thanks viggio24 for sharing your knowledge. I have one small question. How chat apps works when userA starts typeing userB can see that userA is typing when userA click send then immediately userB will receive message. is this achieved with the help of push notification or any other technique.

Comment: In case of chat you don't use push notifications. Normally you establish a direct socket-based communication between the two peers (one as a client other as a server) or you connect both to the same servers (cloud), but also in this case you use a direct socket connection.

Comment: Do you have any tutorial links for socket based communications for ios.

Comment: There is this tutorial, a bit dated but it should still be valid: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server
Another valid resource is Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html
Finally: try to explore the high level frameworks before using sockets directly. Using a server based persistent http communication could be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need server-side logic to handle this. The server knows who needs to see what video so your clients can periodically check a web service for new content.

Even better, look into [Push Notifications](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1). Apple created these for much this reason

Comment: I know much about push notification, so are you telling me to send push notification from server to userB if userA adds some data/Image to server. When userB opens app then download the data/Image ???

Comment: That's exactly what "You need server-side logic to handle this." means and will do for you.

Comment: Is all chat apps follows push notification service to send and receive messages ?